# How can I Customize woocommerce "My Account" page?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm making an online shop page with Woocommerce.

When someone go to "My Account" page to see their recent ordering history or shipping address, My Account page always shows useless welcome message page (which named Dashboard) and customers have to click additional buttons to see useful information they need.

Is there some easy ways to customize the "Dashboard" ? I want to show recent order history and shipping address in there instead of welcome message.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can find all the Woocommerce "My Account" page templates in the following folder:

```
wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/myaccount
```

If you wish to edit any of it I would suggest you to open your theme directory and add a new folder called "woocommerce", and inside it you can copy any files from the original however keep the same file structure but removing the /templates/ subdirectory.

For more info on editing Woocommerce templates you can read [here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/).

Comment: I see that woocommerce is adding `<div class="woocommerce">` inside entry content for this page. Where is it coming from? I'm not able to find it in template sections of my account

Comment: This line helped me "keep the same file structure but removing the /templates/ subdirectory" Thanks.

Comment: Much obliged for ye sire